# S3 Create event notifcation to SQS "Unable to validate the following destionation configurations"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, events, amazon-sqs

Using strictly the management console I created a new S3 bucket and SQS with the default settings. I am then trying to create a notification to SQS queue but whenever I try to create it, it fails with "Unable to validate the following destination configurations". After a couple of hours of searching this error seems mostly related to creating the resources in the wrong order or something with Cloudformation, but I am not using that. Also most of the docs describe connecting the S3 event to an SNS topic, not SQS. I have also spent a lot on time trying to figure out if its policy related. For my SQS policy I have added the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:123:my-sqs",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceAccount": "123"
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Which I think is correct. But this did not help.

How can I get rid of this error and get it working?

Comment: Does the SQS live in another account? Or in the same account?

Comment: Its the same account.

Comment: "something with Cloudformation" - can you show your template? Probably its something wrong with it.

Comment: I don't use CF at all.